# Как нарисовать эллипсоид по формуле в C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Нужно нарисовать эллипсоид по формуле.Но там получается что нужны три точки координат, я нашел только рисование эллипса по 2 точкам и высоте и ширине, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли функции чтобы реализовать это?
Функция по двум координатам:

```
public void DrawEllipse (System.Drawing.Pen pen, int x, int y, int width, int height);
```

Comment: готовой функции - нет, пишите самостоятельно. Либо извлекайте данные из результатов полученных по формуле и используйте ту, которая есть.

Comment: Что такое эллипсойд, и чем он отличается от эллипса?

Comment: @aepot https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4

Comment: То есть, вам нужно нарисовать трехмерную фигуру из вайрфреймов?

Comment: @aepot да, нарисовать эллипсоид.

Comment: Это задача из непростых, и Winforms это немного не про 3D графику. А вы попробовали нарисовать хотя-бы шар таким образом? Или вы хотите, чтобы например я с нуля создал 3D сцену с параметрами перспективы, забабахал функцию рисования эллипсойда и отрисовал ее на форме? Те, кому нужна 3D графика, рисуют в Unity. Но задача правда интересная. Так что там с шаром?